# "Error: Could not find or load main class bin.Main"

Tags: java, executable

I have a project entitled "banking_app" with the following directory structure:

```
banking_app/
|
 — src/
|  |
|   — Main.java
|  |
|   — User.java
|  |
|   — Loan.java
|
 — bin/
   |
    — Main.class
   |
    — User.class
   |
    — Loan.class
```

I'm in the project root directory, and I try execute the following command:

```
myname@computer $ java bin.Main
```

When I press tab, I can select which class I want in /bin, so I thought that java could see it. But whenever I try I only get the following error:

```
Error: Could not find or load main class bin.Main
Cause by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Main (wrong name: bin/Main)
```

I've googled for 20 minutes, and nothing has helped. Does anyone know what's causing this and what the solution is? Thanks.

Comment: Did your web search include [Stack Overflow pages](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=Could+not+find+or+load+main+class) ? How did they fail to help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's `java -cp bin Main` where -cp bin indicates to the java executable where to look for classes and Main is the name of the class.